# the circuit capacitance

Tags: circuit-analysis

The question is:

[image]

The answer is:

[image]

My question is how did he get the 100 (highlighted)?

Source:

PPI PE Power Reference Manual, 4th Edition – Comprehensive Reference Manual for the Closed-Book NCEES PE Exam

Publisher : PPI, A Kaplan Company; Fourth edition (January 31, 2021)

ISBN-10 : 1591267838

ISBN-13 : 978-1591267836

by John A. Camara PE

Comment: Isn’t there a frequency provided somewhere?

Comment: Or simply ignore the slight error in assumptions

Answer (score 5):

That 100 pops up for the omega.
With small approximation I would say that you have a 16.7 Hz system :) one of my favorite ;), the supply of a Swiss, German, Austrian, Swedish railway. 2 * pi * 16.6667 Hz = 104.7 rad/s. (thanks @user2233709)

Otherwise it is just a good round number without physical explanation (I do not think it is easy to find a system with 15.915 Hz of fundamental).

Note: that 100 confirmed by the "100 rad/s" used one line below.

Comment: Looks plausible +1 for analysis